# Search multiple fields with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So what I have is a model `Referent` that has multiple attributes for example `nom` and `prenom`.
I was able to search each attribute in my model using one search value. But then I tried having one `text_field` for each attribute so for `nom` I would have one `text_field` and for `prenom` I would have another.

So it would search for all `Referent` who have that `nom` and that `prenom` but I'm not capable of seperating those two search. Right now it just take one of the value and search in both `nom` and `prenom` with the same value

View:

```
<h2>Search Referent</h2>
<%= form_tag(referents_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Nom" %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Prenom" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-info' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @referents = Referent.all
  if params[:search]
    @referents = Referent.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @referents = Referent.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

Model:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("nom || prenom ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Right now it just seems to take the value of the second `text_field` and use that for the search. I'm using postgresql.

The full view:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Search Referent</h2>
<%= form_tag(referents_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search_nom, params[:search], placeholder: "Nom" %>
<%= text_field_tag :search_prenom, params[:search], placeholder: "Prenom" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-info' %>
<% end %>

<h2>List de Referent</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prenom</th>
    <th>Titre</th>
    <th>Departement</th>
    <th>Cellulaire</th>
    <th>Bureau</th>
    <th>Fax</th>
    <th>Courriel</th>
    <th>Organisme Referent</th>
  </tr>
  <% @referents.each do |referent| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= referent.nom %></td>
    <td><%= referent.prenom %></td>
    <td><%= referent.titre %></td>
    <td><%= referent.departement %></td>
    <td><%= referent.cellulaire %></td>
    <td><%= referent.bureau %></td>
    <td><%= referent.fax %></td>
    <td><%= referent.courriel %></td>
    <td><%= link_to referent.organismereferent.nom_organisation, organismereferent_path(referent.organismereferent_id) %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

</div>
```

Error using Ramon answer[image]

Comment: Your implementation is using two text boxes, and each one is searching a different database column. *So why not send two different HTTP parameters*?

Comment: With your current implementation, you are always going to have the problem that the `prenom` field is being searched with the `nom` value and vice versa.

Comment: The question isn't quite clear. Have you added two search fields? One for nom and another for prenom? Should search be an AND or an OR? As in "nom Like %nom_search% OR prenom LIKE %prenom%? Or "nom Like %nom_search% AND prenom LIKE %prenom%??

Comment: @Surya It should search for a referent who has a `nom` and a `prenom` like the ones specified in the two `text_fields`. So if there's two guys named Mark Richards and Mark Johns. If i leave the `nom` empty and put "Mark" in `prenom` I would get both, But if i put "Mark" in prenom and "Richards" in `nom` I would get only one result.

Comment: @TomLord How would I send them as two different HTTP parameters? I'm pretty new to RoR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
<h2>Search Referent</h2>
<%= form_tag(referents_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search_nom, params[:search_nom], placeholder: "Nom" %>
<%= text_field_tag :search_prenom, params[:search_prenom], placeholder: "Prenom" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-info' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def index
  @referents = Referent.all

  search_nom = params[:search_nom]
  search_prenom = params[:search_prenom]

  @referents = Referent.search(search_nom, search_prenom).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Model

```
def self.search(search_nom, search_prenom)
  where("nom ILIKE ? or prenom ILIKE ?", "%#{search_nom}%", "%#{search_prenom}%")
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `undefined local variable or method search_nom`

Comment: weird, if you use the code like i did here, it wouldn't give that error, is that the full error?

Comment: I did a refactor here, try it like it is

Comment: Check my edit I added all the info concerning the error

Comment: There's one problem with this code, in both `text_field_tag` you have used `params[:search]` for value, so if you put different values in these two fields, you'll see only last field's value in both fields when you return from the search query.

Comment: You should use ` params[:search_nom]` and ` params[:search_prenom]` respectively in these two tags to avoid bug.

Comment: In latest update I see that you have completely removed the values, it would result in blank fields every time a user searches, not a good experience.

Comment: @CNuts try to use or instead of || in your sql, like my update

Comment: @RamonMarques That's working perfectly, I just changed the `or` for a `and` because if i left one of the two empty I would get all the result. Thank you so much :)

Comment: no problem, don't forget to mark answer as accepted and up vote if its useful. You know lol